# How to push only checked checkbox values into an array using angular form controls

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have checkboxes in a form. I am using angular form-controls to build the form and get the values on submit. I want to push only the selected checkboxes into a array.
When I submit the form I get the following values as an object.

```
newForm= {formName: "formone", firstName: true, lastName: false, email: true, phone: false, description: "this is form one"}
```

Now, I want to push only checked value keys into an array. Like

```
array = ["firstName", "email]
```

How can I do this?

I tried with [(ngModel)] binding. But, I want to know how to make it work with form-controls.

Comment: Note: The form consists of other string and number values. I want to push only the checked booleans into the array.

Comment: Do it at your checkbox input element using ng-change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can push the elements that are "true" from the object

```
{
  formName: "formone",
  firstName: true,
  lastName: false,
  email: true,
  phone: false,
  description: "this is form one",
}
```

So the result is `["firstName", "email"]`

```
var newForm = {
  formName: "formone",
  firstName: true,
  lastName: false,
  email: true,
  phone: false,
  description: "this is form one",
};
var array = [];
for (var element in newForm) {
  if (newForm[element] === true) {
    array.push(element);
  }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzq1akb3/) of the above code.